# Android how to show years first in datepicker when onclick the button

Tags: java, android

```
datepickerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

       DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                datePickerDialog.getTouchables().get(0).performClick();

                String strdate=year+"-"+(monthOfYear+1)+"-"+dayOfMonth;
            }
        }, yy, mm, dd);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

I want to display years in datepicker when button is clicked after selecting the years i want to select date.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this simply using below code

```
 DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
 dialog.getDatePicker().getTouchables().get( 0 ).performClick();
```

Use below class to open dialog

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
OnDateOfBirthSelection registrationIIFragment;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    DatePickerDialog abc = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    //18 Years =568,025,136,000 Milliseconds
    double diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - 568025136000.0;
    abc.getDatePicker().setMaxDate((long) diff);
    abc.getDatePicker().getTouchables().get( 0 ).performClick();
    return abc;
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    //  tv1.setText("Year: "+view.getYear()+" Month: "+view.getMonth()+" Day: "+view.getDayOfMonth());
    registrationIIFragment.onDateOfBirthSelected(view.getDayOfMonth() + " - " + (view.getMonth() + 1) + " - " + view.getYear());
}

public void setCallbackListener(OnDateOfBirthSelection registrationIIFragment) {
    this.registrationIIFragment = registrationIIFragment;
}

public interface OnDateOfBirthSelection {
    public void onDateOfBirthSelected(String s);
}  }
```

In button click create above class instance and call show method.

```
 DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.setCallbackListener(this);
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

above code will display output as below image

[image]

Hope this will help thanks

Comment: datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getTouchables().get( 0 ).performClick();

Comment: you just need to add this line datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getTouchables().get( 0 ).performClick(); 
before the datePickerDialog.show();

Comment: i tried this also   datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().getTouchables().get(0).performClick();
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                datePickerDialog.show();

Comment: Please use below class to open  datepicker dialog here is code

Comment: please check i have created class for you above in answer

Comment: k i will try to implement

Comment: newFragment.setCallbackListener(this);newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

Comment: for first error please implement  OnDateOfBirthSelection  interface in your activity and override onDateOfBirthSelected() method.

Comment: for second error please try to extend AppCompatActivity  instead of activity in your java class.

Comment: okay then use   newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176100/discussion-between-deepa-and-sukhbir).